# Xcode: Button back to Main Menu that clears all ViewControllers?

Tags: xcode, segue

I am new to this and I do not understand coding at all, can someone please explain in a very simple way how to fix this?

How do I "go back" from a modal segue that will clear the stack of ViewControllers that are built up from navigating around a sub menu? Currently I have a segue to a sub-menu that has a back button that segue's to the Main Menu. However I ran into memory problems and I need to do it right.

I don't actually have any code in this app, I just have a menu and sub menus that lead to more VC's with images (over 75 images in total). I need the stack of VC's to be cleared from the memory when I go from Sub-menu to Main Menu. I will keep the "back" modal segue from the images to the sub-menu because there are multiple interactions between VC's without going back to the sub menu. So I just need the VC stacks to clear going from the sub menu to main menu. I can link simple code into the back button that is already there but I don't know what I actually need to code to undo the segue and delete the VC's from memory.

Will an unwind segue from sub-menu to main menu delete the VC stack to prevent termination due to memory issues?

Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1kWF.png

Edit: I tried using this Dismiss Segue (http://jeffreysambells.com/2014/02/19/dismissing-a-modal-view-using-a-storyboard-segue) however if I switch between image 1 and image 2 then go back to the submenu the Dismiss Segue to the main menu actually sends me back to image 2 and then I get stuck in the sub menu.

I spent hours trying to get this to work and I have no idea, I just want a button that will clear all ViewControllers and get back to main menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>To clear a view, have an action item (such as a button) on the screen to dismiss. Right-click (or control-click) from the button to the View Controller (the blue thing next to the First Responder button). There will be an IBAction `dismissView:` (or something similar) under the normal options. That will allow you to close the current view and return to the previous view.</s>

Turns out I'm stupid.

Anyways, it's still a very similar process in iOS. There is an "exit" button on the *right* of the First Responder…create a subclass of UIViewController (or just do all this in your existing subclass if you already have). Create a new IBAction method in the subclass called return:

ViewController.h

```
//All of this, if not otherwise noted, is default code upon creating new UIViewController class.

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

//Begin "custom" code
-(IBAction)returned:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue;
//End "custom" code

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

//Begin "custom" code
-(IBAction)returned:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue {
}
//End "custom" code

@end
```

You do not need to put anything inside the method. There will be an "unwind" method in the exit button (`return:`) if you link it now. Bingo!

I am certain there must be a better way to do this, but it works well enough (At least from what I could tell.

(I'm very sorry for telling you the wrong information!)

Edit: It can also be any name; however the argument must be a UIStoryboardSegue pointer. The method must also be in the parent's class. (e.g. `First` -> `Second` -> `Third` means `Third` exits with `secondReturn:` and `Second` exits with `firstReturn:`; anything else e.g. `Third` returning with `firstReturn:` will be nonfunctional in this example)

Comment: When I control click to the View Controller (the button next to first responder) I only get options for an Action Segue: Push, Modal or Custom. I am on Xcode 6.

Comment: Whoops…sorry for the bad information! I'm more used to Cocoa than iOS; I'll update the information accordingly :p

Comment: @droormph Thank you so much this worked like a charm!!! Sorry but one more quick question, how do I make secondreturn and third return?    

(.h)
@ interface UIViewController (Second)
//Begin "custom" code
-(IBAction)Secondreturned:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue;
//End "custom" code 

(.m)
@ implementation UIViewController (Second)
//Begin "custom" code
-(IBAction)Secondreturned:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue {
}
//End "custom" code

Comment: Basically this allowed me to do B > A but how do I unwind from C > B? Do I make a new UIViewController Class or do I add another segue to the same UIViewController given in your answer and how do I tell the program what is A and what is B to unwind back to?

Comment: If you find that C and B can use the same UIViewController subclass, then the same method will work for both views (it will simply unwind one layer up at a time). However, if you have two classes for the two views, the return method must be part of the same class as the parent view controller.